Raspberry Pi 4 SD card filesystem error on first boot (Bad magic number in super-block)
I get the following error on a fresh Raspian install:
resize2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mmcblk0p2 Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mmcblk0p2
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. 

If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running 

e2fsck with an alternate superblock: e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

or

e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

fsck exited with status code 8
mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p2 on /root failed: Invalid argument
Failed to mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 as root file system.

128gb SD card. I burned the image on my Mac using dd:
sudo dd bs=1m if=/Users/aaa/Desktop/2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite.img of=/dev/rdisk6 status=progress

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks!

While you CAN install an OS using dd it is preferable (and safer) to use the imager, which is the recommended method and has the added advantage of checking the installation.
The error indicates a faulty file system; while this may be an isolated failure it may indicate a faulty SD Card. Try again or with another card.
If you continue to get failures you can use the SD Association formatter to perform a low level format and avoid faulty cells.

Thanks for the reply. I tried using the imager but it always fails installation. If burns the SD card but the verification step always fails. After it writes using the imager, I cannot even see the FAT partition on my Mac, which I can if I use dd.

So the obvious conclusion is that the card is faulty (or counterfeit) or your SD Card writer is faulty.

Tried with a different SD card and it worked. Might be a counterfeit card. Thanks for the help.
